# Restore nginx.conf to default elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have accidentally overwritten my nginx.conf file for my elastic beanstalk application. I would like to restore it to its defaults. How do I do this?

An example of the ebxtensions code would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: SSH into the instance manually and restore the file to what it was first.

Comment: Do you have the SSH access to the Server running on your beanstalk?